# What does "double down" mean in this particular context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Apple's CEO, Tim Cook, said this in an interview:

> We're going to double-down on secrecy on products.

I know this phrase is from Blackjack and it means to take more risk and expect higher return. But it doesn't sound like what it means by Tim. Could somebody please give me a hint?

(There is a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/what-does-double-down-mean-when-used-in-a-context-other-than-blackjack) about "double down", but I don't think its explanation applies here either.)

Comment: I think this **is** a duplicate of [What does “double-down” mean when used in a context other than Blackjack?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/what-does-double-down-mean-when-used-in-a-context-other-than-blackjack). Product secrecy is a risk/reward issue, and Cook's usage of *"double-down"* simply reflects the fact that Apple intends to spend more in hopes of getting a high return on the "investment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the quote with a bit more context:

> "We're going to double down on
>   secrecy on products," Cook said, but on
>   other things, "we will be the most
>   transparent company in the world," -
>   like social good and supplier practices.

Double down is originally a blackjack term to play for double or nothing.

It is used more generally to mean make a calculated gamble to double your commitment, to concentrate or focus on something.

But it seems like use is changing, and it's simply means you will try twice as hard (as there's always some inherent risk in everything).

Cook is simply saying Apple are going to be more serious and committed about product secrecy.

The linked question asks about:

> Palin
>   is notorious for doubling-down on
>   perceived missteps, typically blaming a biased media for not
>   telling the whole story.

This is similar; Sarah Palin concentrates and pays extra attention when people claim she makes mistakes, usually trying to deflect blame to the media.

Answer (score 2):

"Doubling down" is a commitment that increases the risk but also increases the possible reward.

It's possibly related to news that Apple is building a cafeteria ([source](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Apple-Restaurant-Secret-Off-Campus-Talking-Spying,15464.html)).  The benefit is that employees can talk openly about secrets at the cafeteria, since nobody else will be there.  The risk is that the money spent on the 20,000 square foot cafeteria will go to waste.

Comment: I'll be honest - when I first read your answer, I thought your theory was a bit of a stretch. After I read the linked article, though, I found both your theory and the article very interesting indeed. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

It means they're going to tighten up security when it comes to products in development.